Identify an old labor prison movie
Older movie was in color, probably technicolor, had a bit of a Cool Hand Luke feel to it, but I didn't see enough of the movie.
Starting point I saw was a cowboy guy robbing a bank alone, but walks into the vault and the teller slamming the door on him.  He may have done it on purpose, as he lights a match in the dark vault, grins and the match goes out.  Next we see a boat arriving at a prison in the middle of a swamp, where the fat warden gives a welcome aboard speech about how it's not even worth escaping based on the surrounding dangers. Place looks like the chain-gang era of thing with wooden huts and bunks.
I suspect this is an escape movie, but I didn't get much more from there.

Possibly Nevada Smith with Steve McQueen where at some point he robs a bank and gets caught (I think he's locked in it) but does it on purpose in order to get to a prison camp in the Louisiana swamps and get his revenge on his parents' killer. And the warden there boasts that no one can escape the swamps. Here's a clip.
